# Moving Windows.Form in Word

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, vsto

Is it possible to move for example a checkbox in word?

There is no method provided for the controls so I tried to remove and then add it again at the new location. My problem with this "solution" is, that the control gets completly white and it's events doesn't work anymore.

Many thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what do you mean by `checkbox` (content control or field?) as far as they are `inline` objects you could move them anywhere within your text.

Comment: @KazJaw
I mean the system.windows.forms checkbox. 

This is the method to add controls: thisdocument.Controls.AddControl(control,left,top,width,height,name);

I get the location through a leftclick on a richtextbox which is placed over the whole page.

Comment: In that case I think you have a new control, and you will need to connect it to the event handlers you need, e.g. theControl.Click += new EventHandler(theControl_Click), and you will need to write a theControl_Click handler if you do not have one. Beware of using dynamically created Windows.Forms objects from VSTO - for example, they will not be saved with the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found a solution ... and it's so simple.

**Switch into the designer mode and you can move it anywhere you want to.**

I know this sounds strange but it works for me and solved my problem.